# Importing classes in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, import

In Eclipse once I put a library on the class path, I can use its classes and then right click on the Class name and Eclipse gives suggestions of various classes with matching names that can be imported.

I wish to do a similar thing in NetBeans, so I mouseover or select the classname and click alt+enter as is suggested. But the only options are for creating the class within the application. The library is opencsv - which I have used without trouble in Eclipse (but I want to try NetBeans).

This is my code (I want to import the classes for CSVReader and FileReader) ... but it just gives me the option to create my own):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

I don't want to have to manually write import statements ... I this what NetBeans expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the menu option "Source -> Fix imports" it will generate all missing  imports for your

Comment: It turns out my computer wasn't working. I reinstalled my operating system, thanks for your help. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can import all missing classes by short cut key
Alt+shift+i